# Prove that $x^2 \in Z(G)$

Tags: group-theory

G is a group, and $|G|=8$ and order of $x$ is $4$. Show $x^2 \in Z(G)$.

My teacher suggested to use the fact that $[G:H]=2, H=<x>$ which means $H$ is a normal subgroup. I didn't reach anywhere with that approach. Thanks, for reading. I am looking for hints.

Comment: What is $H\phantom{}$?

Comment: @anomaly: $H=<x>$. I have solved it. But by using brute force!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You have to show $gx^2g^{-1} = x^2$ for all $g \in G$.
Now, $H$ being normal implies $gx^2g^{-1} \in H$. Further, $x^2$ is the only element of order 2 in H. Can you show that the order of $gx^2g^{-1}$ is 2? (One way is to do it by straightforward calculation: $\le 2$ is easy; and if it were 1, $gx^2g^{-1}$ would be 1, which is impossible because ... . Another way to do it: if you know that the conjugation $y \mapsto g y g^{-1}$ is an automorphism, and automorphisms preserve orders of elements.)

Answer (score 0):

We have $G = H \cup yH$ for some $y \in G$.

To prove that $x^2 \in Z(G)$, it is enough to prove that $x^2$ commutes with $y$.

Now $yH=Hy$ and so $yx=x^n y$ for some $n \in \{0,1,2,3\}$.

Then $x^n = yxy^{-1}$ and so $ord(x^n)=ord(x)$. This only happens for $n \in \{1,3\}$.

Finally, $yx^2 = yxx=x^n yx = x^{2n} y = x^2y$ because $n \in \{1,3\}$.